# How can I find all nodes inside a specific area?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I have a graph and a need to find all nodes that are inside a specific area (polygon). Currently, I'm using BFS algorithm starting with the closest node to the center. A query node is marked as invalid when it's visited but is outside of the polygon.

The problem is that some nodes are not connected to the center so, how can I find all nodes inside the polygon? Here's an example:

[image: Graph]

Comment: You've illustrated the depth=1 stage of your BFS - simply continue it, even if the node you're on is Invalid.

Comment: Two questions: Do the nodes have positions (e.g. (x,y)) attached to them? Do you have to access the nodes via the graph structure?

Comment: @AakashM Considering the example, should work, but on a map, I don't know how many stages would be necessary to visit all nodes.

Comment: @SaiBot Yes all node have positions (coordinates), but I need reach them to get. All I have is the position of center, visited nodes and vertices of the polygon

Comment: If the only way to get the coordinates of nodes is to visit them via the graph, it doesn't matter how many stages might be necessary - you need to do it anyway!

Comment: If you need to get all the nodes inside the polygon, why do you need BFS? Can't you just iterate the list of nodes and test each one? It's not like when you find a node outside of the polygon you don't need to keep searching from there.

Comment: @AakashM, right but this leaves to another questions, when stop to iterate? How can I know that all nodes inside the polygon are visited?

Comment: @jdehesa, It's is because I'm working with a map, so there are millions of nodes.

Comment: If you must use the graph in order to access the nodes then you cannot stop early, you HAVE TO visit all nodes.

Comment: But if you are accessing the first node by its position, why not do it with the other nodes too. You can use a spatial index structure like an R-Tree in order to answer your query.

Comment: @Andrey I see, but I'm not sure if there is any way you can tell whether or not you need to explore the neighbours of a node in order to prune the search (unless you have more constraints, like "all the nodes in the polygon form a clique" or at least "the subgraph of nodes inside of the polygon is connected", but that doesn't match the example). Maybe you could build a quad tree or something to reduce the scope of the search first.

Comment: @jdehesa, I can iterate over all nodes given a bounding box based on min and max coordinates of the polygon.

Comment: @SaiBot, I don't know R-tree structure, I'm going to study about it. Thank you